# Why C# Func<int> cannot be assigned to Func<object>?

Tags: c#, covariant

I've studied Covariant and Contravariant in C#.
and below my code has an error.

```
object a = new object();
int b = 10;

a = b; // not error


Func<object> acO = () => new object();
Func<int> acI = () => 1;

acO = acI; // error
```

Error Message:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Func' to type 'System.Func'.

I thought that if int -> object is possible, Func -> Func will be possible.
but it is not.

I think value type will be copied to use when it is returned unlike reference type(object) and it can cause unintentional operation(like exception). Is my guess correct?

I'm looking forward to your wise answers.
Thank you for reading.

Comment: `int` to `object` is a boxing conversion rather than a reference conversion as you'd get with deriving classes, which is why (for better or worse) the compiler will not allow this implicitly, as it would need to generate a new delegate under the covers. `acO = () => acI()` works, since you're doing the boxing yourself, explicitly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [Variance in Delegates (C#)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/covariance-contravariance/variance-in-delegates#variance-in-generic-type-parameters-for-value-and-reference-types) docs:

> Variance for generic type parameters is supported for reference types only.

A nice [blog post](https://ericlippert.com/2009/03/03/representation-and-identity/) diving into the topic by Eric Lippert:

> All the built-in reference conversions are identity-preserving. This is why covariant and contravariant conversions of interface and delegate types require that all varying type arguments be of reference types. To ensure that a variant reference conversion is always identity-preserving, all of the conversions involving type arguments must also be identity-preserving. The easiest way to ensure that all the non-trivial conversions on type arguments are identity-preserving is to restrict them to be reference conversions.

Comment: I thought delegates (including `Func<T>`) _were_ reference types in .NET?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen yes, but the quote is about type parameters. Similar quote can be found in the doc regarding variance in generic interfaces.